# BufferedImage getSubimage throws exception with seemingly good arguments

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Java 8 here. Trying to stick with the `BufferedImage` API and not delve into JavaFx land.

I have a JPG image that is 768 pixel wide and 432 pixels in height. I want to crop a *centered* 400x400 pixel square out of the center of it using [`BufferedImage#getSubimage(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

I have the following code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageTempFile);

int dim = 400;
int xCropBuffer, yCropBuffer;
xCropBuffer = (image.getWidth() - dim) / 2;
yCropBuffer = (image.getHeight() - dim) / 2;

log.info("width = " + image.getWidth() + ", height = " + image.getHeight() + ", dim = " + dim + ", xCropBuffer = " + xCropBuffer + ", yCropBuffer = " + yCropBuffer);

image = image.getSubimage(xCropBuffer, yCropBuffer + dim, dim, dim);
```

At runtime this throws the following exception:

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:1248)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(BufferedImage.java:1202)
    at java_awt_image_BufferedImage$getSubimage.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.myapp.DefaultMediaService.uploadImage(DefaultMediaService.java:56)
    at com.myapp.MediaService$uploadImage.call(Unknown Source)
```

And the logs print the following message right before the exception is thrown:

```
width = 768, height = 432, dim = 400, xCropBuffer = 184, yCropBuffer = 16
```

So I'm passing in `image.getSubimage(184, 416, 400, 400)` arguments...shouldn't this be OK?! The image is 768x432, so (184, 416) should be a valid coordinate for its upper-left corner, and 184 + 400 < 768 and 416 - 400 > 0. So all these parameters should map to a valid 400x400 rectangle inside the image, right?

Comment: The arguments are x, y, w, h, so y + h will be greater than the original image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing an image is not like drawing a text, where the ascend runs from baseline to smaller y coordinates. The image is specified by its upper left corner and extending towards the greater coordinates for both, x and y. Hence, you should not specify `+ dim` for the y coordinate.

```
BufferedImage oldImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile),
    newImage = oldImage.getSubimage(
        (oldImage.getWidth()-dim)/2, (oldImage.getHeight()-dim)/2, dim, dim);
ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", imageFile);
```

For completeness, since there seem to have been some confusion in your previous question, here some alternative for achieves the same image transformation, which can be used as template for other image operations:

- via `BufferedImageOp`

  ```
  BufferedImage oldImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile),
      newImage = new BufferedImage(dim, dim, oldImage.getType());
  BufferedImageOp op = new AffineTransformOp(
      AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
          -(oldImage.getWidth()-dim)/2, -(oldImage.getHeight()-dim)/2),
      AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
  op.filter(oldImage, newImage);
  ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", imageFile);
  ```
- via `Graphics`

  ```
  BufferedImage oldImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile),
      newImage = new BufferedImage(dim, dim, oldImage.getType());
  Graphics2D gfx = newImage.createGraphics();
  gfx.drawImage(oldImage,
                -(oldImage.getWidth()-dim)/2, -(oldImage.getHeight()-dim)/2, null);
  gfx.dispose();
  ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", imageFile);
  ```

In either case, the cropping to a desired size is implied by making the target image smaller than the original one.
Then, the source image only has to get translated by (-x, -y) to select the desired detail rectangle.

Comment: Thanks @Holger (+1) but your method arguments don't make sense to me. If my image is 768x432 that means I'd be passing in `x=184` and `y=16` which is actually the **bottom** left corner, no? Or do I have my origin/axes inverted? Is (0,0) top-left or bottom-left (w.r.t. typical mathematical cartesian coordinates)?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I'd assume (0,0) is top-left

Comment: Ahhh, dang, that makes sense. Well, it doesn't make *sense*, you'd think Sun would have modeled their coordinate system after the standard Cartesian model, but oh well, at least that explains it.

Comment: Well, using `(0, 0)` for the upper left screen corner is the standard behavior for most systems and programming languages and Sun had to follow that model to make Java accepted by the programming community of that time…

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty simple. The height is 432, and you are specifying the upper-left corner as (182, 416). Next, you ask it to get 400 pixels down. So you get 432 < 416 + 400 which means that the bottom of the frame you want to select is greater than the height of the image.

Comment: Well then aren't the API docs misleading? The `y` argument is specified as the y-coord of the upper-left corner, no? So if I want my upper left corner to be at (184, 416), shouldn't the `getSubimage` method be subtracing the height from 416? And not adding to it?! Either way, what should my arguments be?!

Comment: If your *upper left corner* is at (184, 416), then the width is added to the x, and the height is added to y